# Remove Duplicate Icons In Show Applications

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, duplicate

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and proceeded to install several programs. One of the programs, Gitkraken now has 2 icons when I opened SHOW APPLICATIONS while other installed programs are not showing at all. So my questions are:

1) How do I remove duplicate icons in Show Applications?
2) How do I add an icon in Show Applications?

FYI, I have checked /usr/share/applications and there is only one gitkraken.desktop. So I am not sure why I have 2 Gitktaken icons in Show Applications. Any insight on how to solve these 2 issues will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.local/share/applications/`?

Comment: I got similar problem. ~/.local/share$ find . -name "*chema*" found 4 copies of ./applications/DbSchema-[0-3].desktop. Thanks for Pomsky. Why don't you post this as an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Pomsky's comment, I had four identical icons for the DbSchema program in my "show applications" panel.  Going into $HOME/.local/share/applications I indeed have four copies: DbSchema-[0-3].desktop.

```
rm DbSchema-0.desktop DbSchema-1.desktop DbSchema-2.desktop
```

Solved my problem.

/usr/share/applications my have similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrade from Ubuntu Mate 19.04 to 20.04 I have received issue with double icons of network-manager in the tray.

According to answer of [Kemin Zhou](https://askubuntu.com/a/1096917/281923) I have check my `$HOME/.local/share/applications` folder and I found there 3 files: `mozo-made.desktop mozo-made-1.desktop mozo-made-2.desktop`. I have removed files: `mozo-made-1.desktop mozo-made-2.desktop` and then rebooted the system and my issue with double netwok-manager icons was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

A nice tool for me is Alacarte, just a few clicks to remove double sublime icons from the app launcher.

Install it from the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Comment: What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The previous answers are good, they forgot about snap.

Check the package availability in each of the package managers:

```bash
snap list
```

or

```bash
dpkg --list
```

If the package are found once, then see [datMaster](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245177/913290) answer.